# WPF Style Hierarchy

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have created a custom control, ColorToggleButton, which inherits ToggleButton.  In a corresponding .xaml file, a  for ColorToggleButton is specific via TargetType and BasedOn ToggleButton.

```
<Style TargetType="ctl:ColorToggleButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}">
```

This works fine, but if I apply another style in a window using x:Key, as in

```
<Style x:Key="SameContent"><Setter Property="Content" Value="Same Content" /></Style>
<ctl:ColorToggleButton Style={StaticResource SameContent} />
```

the old style seems to get wiped out completely and replaced with the new one.  I can  circumvent the problem by using BasedOn

```
<Style x:Key="SameContent" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ctl:ColorToggleButton}}"><Setter Property="Content" Value="Same Content" /></Style>
<ctl:ColorToggleButton Style={StaticResource MyKey} />
```

but this seems counterintuitive to me, seeing as I wouldn't use the BasedOn attribute if I was applying styles to a normal ToggleButton or some other default control.  Is this the standard way of implementing your own controls?  Am I doing something horribly wrong?

Edit: The static constructor of ColorToggleButton is as follows:

```
static ColorToggleButton()
{
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ColorToggleButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ColorToggleButton)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your control, did you provide static constructor with [DefaultStyleKeyProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.defaultstylekey.aspx) override?

```
static ColorToggleButton()
{
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ColorToggleButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ColorToggleButton)));
}
```